# Invalid property value for align-text css

Tags: css

I have set the `text-align:none;` for both body and my list.

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:none;
    font-family: arial, verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#nav .menu{
    background:#F27739;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
    from(#F27739),to(#D95B1C));
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:50px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:none;
}
```

But in [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) I detected that both of these `text-align:none;` are invalid property values. I don't understand, why?

Comment: What would `none` aligned text look like exactly? Like a shaken up Scrabble board? ;-P

Comment: I better don't ask anything about front-end.....Such a noob question and -4 reputation ;(

Comment: Hint: This applies to *any* language, whether front-end or back-end: If you get an "invalid argument/value/parameter/whatever", look up in the appropriate documentation what the valid values are. Documentation, documentation, documentation! :)

Comment: Yes I will keep in mind, DOCUMENTATION!!!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text-align: none` is invalid.

If you want to have it be the default alignment, you need to do:

`text-align: inherit`

But, you should really set it to one of the following:

`text-align: left` or `text-align: justify` or `text-align: center` or `text-align: right`

Answer (score 3):

`none` is not a valid value for `text-align`. You can see the valid values here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

- left    Aligns the text to the left
- right   Aligns the text to the right
- center  Centers the text
- justify     Stretches the lines so that each line has equal width (like in newspapers and magazines)
- inherit     Specifies that the value of the text-align property should be inherited from the parent element

Answer (score 2):

`none` is not a valid value for the `text-align` property.

Valid values include:

> [ start | end | left | right | center ] ||  ] | justify |
>   match-parent | start end

[See the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

Answer (score 2):

The default value for text-align is left, there isn't a none value. As the text has to physically be aligned somewhere. If you want to reset the text-align, set it to left or inherit.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Answer (score 1):

`text-align` takes following properties:

`start | end | left | right | center ] || <string> ] | justify | match-parent | start end`

[**More info here.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

Answer (score 0):

Because `none` value is not available with `text-align`.

option with text-align

```
text-align: left
text-align: right
text-align: center
text-align: justify
text-align: start
text-align: end
text-align: inherit
```

For more details refer [link](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/)

Answer (score 0):

`none` *is* an invalid property of `text-align`. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-align

Just use the default alignment for the language you're using i.e. `left`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `text-align` doesn't support `none`. Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Simple because there is no such property take a look at this : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

but try to leave it blank and or use the inherit and it will be aligned according to the parent/wrapper